# Best way to handle bad or inappropriate present?

Tags: birthday, presents

What is the best way to handle a situation where one of the presents a child gets is either bad (broken toy); or a dangerous toy for their age (fully functional real Ninja sword); or inappropriate (adult party game, religious item from another religion).

The assumption here is that the child was present for the unwrapping and already saw the present and may get excited over the item immediately.

While the obvious grown-up advice is to return the present with the return reciept; I have almost never observed child presents having return reciepts so that's not an option.

Age range late preschool or elementary school.

This question specifically pertains to handling the gifts from the perspective of your child, NOT how to handle the situation with the person who have the bad gift afterwards

Comment: I think this and your other present question should be combined into one.  Two overly similar questions posted at the same time is unnecessary.

Comment: @joe aside from being about presents how are they even remotely related?

Answer (score 6):

you're in charge of allowing or not your kid to play with that present.

accept it and say thanks, then at home, talk to your kid about why you don't think it's a good idea for him/her to play with that toy and say you're gonna save it for when he/she is old enough to play with it.

end of story :-)